# onClick fullscreen in React without wrapper or provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Is there a way to enter fullscreen mode from any component in React without using providers or wrapper div?

I know that fullscreen mode can be achieved by using packages like fscreen or react-full-screen, but I'd like to omit that.

If wrapper or provider is obligatory, what's the most efficient way to enter fullscreen?
I have a lot of components and different views and I want to have a button that onClick enters fullscreen of the whole page, regardless to where that button is inside DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to enter Full screen mode, you can run this on click:

`Element.requestFullscreen()`

And if you want to exit it you can call this method:

`document.exitFullscreen()`